# Run Task after View loaded without ViewModel class in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Hi I want a task to run immediately after the view is opened without need for ViewModel class

This is how I do it right now

```
 public class ContributorsViewModel : DemoViewModelBase<Model>
    {
        public ContributorsViewModel()
        {
            Task.Run(() => DataList = new DataService().GetDataList());
        }
    }
```

DemoViewModelBase:

```
 public class DemoViewModelBase<T> : BindableBase
        {
            private IList<T> _dataList;
    
            public IList<T> DataList
            {
                get => _dataList;
                set => SetProperty(ref _dataList, value);
            }
        }
```

Bootstrapper:

```
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ContributorsView>();
```

I do not know how to do this without a viewmodel

Comment: As a note, any awaitable method call (like Task.Run) should be awaited. You can however not await anything in a constructor. There should be some kind of async Initialize method that would be awaited.

Comment: @Clemens My question is not about the task, it is about how to call in MVVM without the need for a view model.

Comment: That's why I wrote "as a note". Besides that, the obvious way to run a Task "*after view loaded*" is an async Loaded event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything you want in code-behind, for example subscribe to the `Loaded` event:

```
internal class ContributorsView
{
    public ContributorsView()
    {
         InitializeComponents();
         Loaded += async (s, e) => await Task.Run( ...whatever... );
    }
}
```

But keep in mind:

- you won't be able to *test* this
- you do not get the benefit of injected dependencies

> without [...] ViewModel class

This seems to be a really bad idea(*), because what you want to do is essentially what view models are there for.

(*) unless you have some architectural that you didn't reveal

Comment: I do not want to use code-Behind I know this can be done through Bootstrapper but I do not know how?